# SELinux does not allow ps command in PHP

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php, selinux

I use this piece of code to check if myservice is running in php.  `exec("ps -A | grep -i myservicename | grep -v grep 2>&1", $output);`. $output is always empty. But after executing `setenforce 0` it works fine. So SELinux is preventing httpd from executing this command. Also audit2why gives me the following message.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1503739681.450:2905): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=11273 comm="ps" name="11017" dev="proc" ino=97841 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=dir
    Was caused by:
            Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

            You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

How can I tell SELinux to allow httpd to execute my command?

**UPDATE**

Result of `audit2allow -a` is:

```
#============= httpd_sys_script_t ==============
allow httpd_sys_script_t NetworkManager_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t NetworkManager_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t abrt_watch_log_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t abrt_watch_log_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t auditd_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t auditd_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t crond_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t crond_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t firewalld_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t firewalld_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t fsdaemon_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t fsdaemon_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t getty_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t getty_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t httpd_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t httpd_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t init_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t init_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t initrc_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t initrc_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t irqbalance_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t irqbalance_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t kernel_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t kernel_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t lsmd_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t lsmd_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t lvm_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t lvm_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t mysqld_safe_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t mysqld_safe_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t mysqld_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t mysqld_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t policykit_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t policykit_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t postfix_master_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t postfix_master_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t postfix_pickup_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t postfix_pickup_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t postfix_qmgr_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t postfix_qmgr_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t sshd_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t sshd_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t syslogd_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t syslogd_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t system_dbusd_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t system_dbusd_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t systemd_logind_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t systemd_logind_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t tuned_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t tuned_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t udev_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t udev_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t unconfined_service_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t unconfined_service_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_sys_script_t unconfined_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_sys_script_t unconfined_t:dir getattr;

#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t etc_runtime_t:sock_file write;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t mysqld_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t self:rawip_socket create;

#============= mysqld_safe_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow mysqld_safe_t var_lib_t:lnk_file read;

#============= mysqld_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow mysqld_t etc_runtime_t:dir { add_name remove_name write };

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow mysqld_t etc_runtime_t:file { create rename unlink write };

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow mysqld_t etc_runtime_t:sock_file { create unlink };

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow mysqld_t var_lib_t:lnk_file { getattr read };
```

**SOLUTION**

This command solved my problem.

`semanage permissive -a httpd_sys_script_t`

OR

`semanage permissive -a httpd_t`

Now httpd can run any command.

Comment: Setting httpd as permissive is not a good solution, the permissive mode disables your SELinux security and logs the entries into audit files, it's a kind of debugging mode.

Answer (score 1):

Run the `audit2allow -a` command to view the **Type Enforcement** rule that allows the denied access:

```
audit2allow -a

#============= certwatch_t ==============
allow certwatch_t var_t:dir write;
```

To use the rule displayed by `audit2allow -a`, run the `audit2allow -a -M mycertwatch` command as the Linux root user to create custom module. The `-M` option creates a **Type Enforcement file (.te)** with the name specified with `-M`, in your current working directory:

```
audit2allow -a -M mycertwatch

******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i mycertwatch.pp

~]# ls
mycertwatch.pp  mycertwatch.te
```

Also, `audit2allow` compiles the **Type Enforcement** rule into a policy package (.pp). To install the module, run the `semodule -i mycertwatch.pp` command as the Linux root user.

Comment: What is `mycertwatch`? Is it `ps` command in my case?

Comment: Yes. Using `audit2allow -a` you will be able to see the Type Enforcement rule that is denying access. I used an example in this answer, which is `mycertwatch`

Comment: Please see the update. What should I do with the result of `audit2allow -a` command?

Comment: Can you do this : `grep kernel_t /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M ps`

Comment: And then `semodule  -i ps.pp`

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: What is the output of `grep kernel_t /var/log/audit/audit.log`

Comment: Check this blog out . Might be able to help you. http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/24750.html